# Connecting Microsoft SQL Server using pyspark, throws Error:

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Please guide me the steps to connect and read data from MS SQL by using Pyspark. 
Below is my code and the error message that i am getting when i am trying to load data from MS SQL Server. Please guide me.

```py
import urllib
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

APP_NAME = 'My Spark Application'

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("APP_NAME").setMaster("local[4]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

sqlcontext = SQLContext(sc)

jdbcDF = sqlcontext.read.format("jdbc")\
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver:XXXX:1433")\
  .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")\
  .option("dbtable", "dbo.XXXX")\
  .option("user", "XXXX")\
  .option("password", "XXX")\
  .load()
```

******************************ERROR***************************************

```
teway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in d
eco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\protoco
l.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o66.load.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable
(JDBCRDD.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(J
DBCRelation.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.
createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation
(DataSource.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:122)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Have you added jdbcdrivers in your spark folder ?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:

Include **mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar** file into jars sub-folder( ex: C:\spark\spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7\jars) or you can paste any of the jar file based on your system.

Then use the following command to connect to MS SQL server & create the Spark Dataframe:

dbData = spark.read.jdbc("jdbc:sqlserver://servername;databaseName:ExampleDB;user:username;password:password","tablename")

Answer (score 0):

1. Download mssql-jdbc-x.x.x.jrex.jar file (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. Run the following code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext

appName = "PySpark SQL Server Example - via JDBC"
master = "local[*]"
conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName(appName) \
    .setMaster(master) \
    .set("spark.driver.extraClassPath","path/to/mssql-jdbc-x.x.x.jrex.jar")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark = sqlContext.sparkSession

database = "mydatabase"
table = "dbo.mytable"
user = "username"
password  = "password"

jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver" , "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://serverip:1433;databaseName={database}") \
    .option("dbtable", "mytable") \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .load()

jdbcDF.show()
```